# WP_Query, custom fields and no pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-fields

I have this code:

```
<?php $q = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'oferty'
        ));
    ?>
    <?php while ($q -> have_posts()) : $q -> the_post(); ?>
    <!-- .post | id: <? echo $post->ID; ?> -->
        <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <div class="entry">
                <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                <small><?php echo get_field('bank'); ?></small>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
            <?php if($thumb) : ?>
            <div class="bankimg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb[0];?>')"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </article>
        <!-- /.post | id: <? echo $post->ID; ?> -->
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } ?>
```

It uses `wp_query` to list all the posts from post type `oferty`. I set in WordPress options limit of posts to 2 and it works - but no pagination shows up. I tried WP PageNavi, WP Pagination and normal WordPress' prev/next linsk.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the pagination parameters when querying for custom post types:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Specifically, try this:

```
$q = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'oferty',
    'posts_per_page' => 2
));
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. Also, please note, I am using `wp_query`, not `query_posts`, which replaces many things (like, for example, pagination).

Comment: @TomekBuszewski - So where has he mentioned query_posts exactly?

Comment: He didn't, but when you use `wp_query`, if you don't set `posts_per_page`, it takes WordPress' value from admin. `query_posts` doesn't.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski Ah, interesting!!  Thanks for the explanation, I wasn't aware of that.